# Calculate total experience in SQL in terms of months - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

My table is like:

```
id |  prev_experience_in_month   |   current_company_experience
1  |   13                        |    1.4
2  |   15                        |     .5
3  |   20                        |     3.0
```

`current_company_experience` is calculated using the following formula, in the form `year.month`:

```
CONCAT(DATEDIFF(YEAR, HIRE_DATE, GETDATE()), '.', DATEDIFF(MM, HIRE_DATE, GETDATE())%12)
```

I want the output to look like:

```
id   prev_experience_in_month      curret_company_experience   total_experience
1     13                             1.4                             2.5
2     15                             .5                              1.3
3     20                             3.0                             4.6
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @dns_nx convert the month values into year.month format and concatenate prev experience and current experience as total experience in year.month format

Comment: You can simply add both calculations as forth column.

Comment: @AnuAntony Check my updated answer, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Hope this helps you:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(ID INT, prev_experience_in_month INT, curret_company_experience VARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(1,13,1.11)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(2,15,0.5)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES(3,20,3.0)

SELECT *
    ,CAST((prev_experience_in_month+(LEFT(curret_company_experience,CHARINDEX('.',curret_company_experience)-1)*12+RIGHT(curret_company_experience,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(curret_company_experience))-1)))/12 AS VARCHAR)
        +'.'+CAST((prev_experience_in_month+(LEFT(curret_company_experience,CHARINDEX('.',curret_company_experience)-1)*12+RIGHT(curret_company_experience,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(curret_company_experience))-1)))%12 AS VARCHAR) [total_experience]
FROM @MyTable
```

**Output:**

```
ID          prev_experience_in_month curret_company_experience               total_experience
----------- ------------------------ --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1           13                       1.11                                     3.0
2           15                       0.5                                     1.8
3           20                       3.0                                     4.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following calculation for change the `prev_experience_in_month` to YearDec value like `concat(cast((prev_experience_in_month/12) as unsigned),'.',(prev_experience_in_month%12))`

```
select id,
concat(cast((prev_experience_in_month/12) as unsigned),'.',(prev_experience_in_month%12)) prev_experience_in_year_dec,
CONCAT(DATEDIFF(YEAR, HIRE_DATE, GETDATE()), '.', DATEDIFF(MM, HIRE_DATE, GETDATE())%12) curret_company_experience,
(concat(cast((prev_experience_in_month/12) as unsigned),'.',(prev_experience_in_month%12)) + CONCAT(DATEDIFF(YEAR, HIRE_DATE, GETDATE()), '.', DATEDIFF(MM, HIRE_DATE, GETDATE())%12))

total_experience
from mytable
```